# How to insert post meta values in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post

How to insert post meta values while adding a post? I am using wp_insert_post function to insert the post. For using the "add_post_meta" function, we need to specify the post ID. How can I add the values at the time of inserting post? Is there any way to do this!?

regards - dj

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Suppose you have created an array to insert post

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'   => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_type'    => $type,
    'post_status'  => $status           
    );
```

get the new inserted post_id with

```
$id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

then insert values in wp_postmeta table by passing parameters like `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`:

```
update_post_meta($id,'total_payments',$amount);
update_post_meta($id,'downcount',$downcount);
```

try it.

Comment: Very much appreciated.

Comment: This makes heavy use of the database. Instead, you can add 'meta_input'   => array(
        'test_meta_key' => 'value of test_meta_key',
    ) to the $new_post array

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion.I found the solution myself. We need to use the Post ID that returns by the function wp_insert_post. It returns the post ID value for the successful posting.

Comment: You must @Heer Makwana's answer because it does exactly what you say, but it has the example which is the most important.