# Insert new WordPress post with custom meta fields programmatically

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can you create and insert new posts containing already filled [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) programmatically into your database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361009/how-to-insert-post-meta-values-in-wordpress

Comment: There's nothing special about ACF fields. They are simple meta fields...You can use standard WordPress functions to [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta), which removes the unnecessary external dependency on ACF.

Comment: When I try to use `update_post_meta($post_id, 'description', 'description text ');` either with field name ("description") or field key ("field_5629f95fc4108") it does not work for me. The post is created but the meta are not updated.The only way I made it work was with `update_field` that's why I wanted to share this little "how to". Maybe I should change the title and the answer to explain why I suggest this solution ?

Answer (score 7):

1. **Say you have an ACF group with 3 fields each of a different type**

   - description (type **Text**)
   - image (type **Image**)
   - categories (type **Taxonomy**)
2. **prepare a basic post**

```
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => 'My post',
        'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1
    );
```

2. **insert post and keep the created post id**

```
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

3. **then update values of custom fields using the post id**

```
    // description (text type field)
    update_field('field_5629f95fc4108', 'description for post', $post_id);

    // image (Image type field)
    $image_id = array(1, 2, 3);
    update_field('field_5621199730caa', $image_id, $post_id);

    // categories (Taxonomy field type)
    $categories_ids = array(1, 2, 3);
    update_field('field_56211b33d0018', $categories_ids, $post_id);
```

Comment: if you'd like to set a value for a relationship field type just use an array containing the post ID’s you wish to have the relationship as the 'value' argument, also you can usually use field names instead of id's so for instance: update_field('related_exam_sessions', array(1011, 1012), $post_id);